# Report viewer is not showing crystal report

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

***I am using VisualStudio 2019 and .Net Framework 4.7.2 version.***
I downloaded the crystal report SP26 by using this link: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/crystal-reports-download-for-visual-studio/#crystal-reports-for-visual-studio.
In the report viewer Loading function, I have bellow code:

```
private void crystalReportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    mySqlConnection.Open();

    rd.Load(@"C:\Users\papsa\TTM-Management\TTM-Management\CrylecturerReport.rpt");
            
    string st = "SELECT time_slot,Session FROM last_time_table WHERE default_year = '"+year+"' AND Session LIKE '%"+lecname+"%' ORDER BY time_slot ASC";

    MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(st, mySqlConnection);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "lecturers");
    rd.SetDataSource(ds);
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
}
```

When I run the project it displays me only the report viewer. at least it is not showing the margins of the crystal report.
does anyone knows the reason?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the phpMyAdmin application, so I've edited to remove that tag.